# Как настроить сортировку по числам в строках в Excel?

Tags: excel, сортировка

Есть столбец данных

```
К1
К2
К10
К3
```

Формат ячеек числовой. При нажатии сортировки (Главная->Сортировка и фильтр->Сортировка от А до Я) колонка принимает вид:

```
К1
К10
К2
К3
```

Как правильно настроить сортировку для моей таблицы.
Хотелось бы что бы сортировка работала так:

ПРИ ВОЗРАСТАНИИ:

```
К1
К2
К3
К10
```

ПРИ УБЫВАНИИ:

```
К10
К3
К2
К1
```

Answer (score 0):

В соседнем столбце можно формулой выделить числовую часть и сортировать по ней. Или написать сортировку на VBA, которая реализует такой же алгоритм.

Если количество букв в начале постоянно, то формула может быть такая: =MID(ссылка на соседнюю ячейку; позиция первой цифры (в данном случае 2); 255 (это длинна с запасом))

Разделитель аргументов в формуле - в зависимости от региональных настроек, в приведённом примере точка с запятой. На русском функция называется ПСТР.

[image: Снимок экрана]